# Rabbitmq with pika: worker blocks on basic_consume callback

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I have some simple code that consumes messages from several rabbitmq queues.

It works fine if it starts with no messages in the queues.

But if there is a message in one of the queues upon startup, it will immediately process that message once it calls basic_consume for that queue and the not proceed through the loop to the other basic_consume calls.

How can I prevent it from doing that?

```
def handle_message(ch, method, properties, body):
    # do something
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbitmq_address))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
for q in queues:
    channel.queue_declare(str(q), durable=True)
    channel.basic_consume(handle_message, queue=str(q))
print "starting to consume..."
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: This is probably a bug. Pika had a similar bug (see [Issue 86](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/86)) two years ago. Are you running the latest release?

Comment: Thanks, I am running an older version ( 0.9.8 ) so thats probably it, for now I've worked around it by using SelectConnection instead of BlockingConnection